# UITableView and UICollectionView interaction ios?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview

Please can anyone help me to achieve something like this-
(developing for iPad iOS7) In `UIViewController` i have UITableView & `UICollectionView`(like `splitViewController`).I just want to change image in `UICollectionView` when i tap on `UITableViewCell`.(I am using `button` over `tableViewCell` and collecting  index in `NSInteger`).

Please help me to achieve this,I am trying from so many days,but can't achieve till now. :(

Here is the code what i have done till now.

In my `viewDidLoad`:

```
self.collectionViewImages=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1.jpg",@"2.jpg",@"3.jpg",nil] ;
```

Then in `CollectionViewMethods`:

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
     return 1;
}
-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    return [_collectionViewImages count];

}


-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
             cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

   UICollectionViewCell *myCell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"
                                forIndexPath:indexPath];


   NSString *collectionViewImageName=[self.collectionViewImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   UIImageView * collectionImage = (UIImageView*)[myCell viewWithTag:11];

  collectionImage.image =[UIImage imageNamed:collectionViewImageName];

 return myCell;
}
```

Then on ButtonClick(ofTableViewCell)--
(i am collecting tag of each button in `NSInteger` and using that property in `numberOfItemsInSection`  like this,

```
-(void)btnTapped:(id)sender{
int tag= [(UIButton *)sender tag];
NSLog(@"Button Pressed%d",tag);
_buttonIndex=tag;
//_buttonIndex is NSInteger property
//If i add object in NSMutableArray and call reloadData my UI hangs here only.
//If  I empty my NSMutableArray and add new objects in it and then call reloadData, I am getting NSRangeException. 
}
```

And now i am using this property in `numberOfItemsInSection` as...

```
if (_buttonIndex==1){

     [collectionImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[_array1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
     //My _array1 has 4 objects and my collectionViewImages array has 7 objects.

    }
```

i am getting error message as

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', 
reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 4 beyond bounds [0 .. 3]'
```

Answer (score 0):

Its crashing because you are trying to get an item from the array at index 4. But there are only indexes: 0,1,2,3.

Double check the contents of array1 on line (if it crashes here):

```
[collectionImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[_array1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
```

Otherwise find the other place where you call `objectAtIndex`and check if it crashes there.

Comment: The stupidity which I was doing that ,I created the `property` for `UICollectionView` but forgot to connect with Interface Builder. :p